# How to make a condition using time of day?

Tags: javascript

How do I make a condition by the time? 
For example, the output of the next day of the calendar every day after 18: 30 UTC+3
The current day is displayed until 18: 30 Moscow time

I got stuck on checking for minutes, since the condition will not be met for up to 30 minutes every hour

```js
let date = new Date();
let hoursNow = date.getUTCHours() + 3; 
let minutesNow = date.getMinutes(); 
if (hoursNow > 17 && minutesNow > 30) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // add 1 day 
}

// Month
const month=["января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря"];

document.querySelector('.text_block').innerHTML = date.getDate() + ' ' + month[date.getMonth()];
```

```html
<div class="text_block"></div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine as is but just keep in mind that since you want Timezone specific information you should probably stick with [`date.getUTCMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes) instead of `date.getMinutes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your condition to just check for the minutes in the 18th hour and after that, just ignore the minutes:

```js
if (hour == 18 && minutes > 30) || (hours > 18) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1); // add 1 day 
}
```

and, as suggested by @Sherif:
use `date.getUTCMinutes()` instead of
`date.getMinutes()` to have timezon independent information.